# How to find the XPINC port in Notes Client without opening an xpage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I've used the syntax detailed [here](http://blog.techdriveactive.de/2012/11/open-attachments-in-xpage-in-client.html) to access an image from an attachment in another document, and this works.  I've also taken the url that is generated and pasted it into a Notes client form as an *img src="..."*.  It works there too.  However, I can't find a way of finding the port number that XPages in Notes Client (XPINC) uses.

e.g. my URL starts with *http://127.0.0.1:64669/xsp/* but the 64669 changes from session to session, and user to user. In the first instance this port was found by examining the URL of the xpage that contained the link, but as I want to do this in a conventional Notes form, I want some way of finding that port number.

Alternatively, if anyone knows a simple way to embed a very small XPage in a Notes client form...?

Second alternative: something along the lines of "Microsoft.XMLHTTP" that will allow the "Notes://" protocol instead of "http://"?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Do you need XSP engine to serve your resource by url, or you just want to get some image resource?

Comment: Off the hip: the xpages servlet engine is an Eclipse component. Using a plugin you might be able to query the runtime. The other option: load a mini xpage as a sidebar and let the page get the port in client side js

Comment: I wouldn't access the attachment through the XPages UI. I'd just go via the normal Notes back-end. XPages is the UI. Don't kill yourself trying to get the XPiNC on a Notes form when you could just access it from back end like @stwissel shows in the first example in blog post.

Comment: What I was originally planning to do was attach a PNG in a RT field in a Notes database.  I then wanted to display that PNG (the image, not the attachment) in another Notes document.  So, I tried the normal Notes URL method, but discovered that ?OpenElement doesn't work in Notes URLs.
Then I read the link that I posted, and found that I can easily display the image in an XPage. However, we do not want to change our forms to XPages, so I ws looking for another way to automatically display the image.

Comment: @DavidNavarre which blog post do you mean?

Comment: I may have found a solution, as the port number appears to be set in [...]\Lotus\Notes\Data\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.ibm.pvc.webcontainer.prefs as the lastPort value.
Some testing required, but I think I might have cracked it in a simple way.

Comment: @PhilMJones, I meant the one you linked to in your blog: http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-86QKNM